# Add Custom Class to children of Specific Wordpress Menu Only

Tags: wordpress, class, menu

I have created a Custom Menu in Wordpress called 'Primary Nav' and I want to create a function to add a custom class to all it's li children so that it can trigger a slider. I know from Wordpress that you can use conditional statements like:-

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
 if(is_page()){ //Notice you can change the conditional from is_single() and $item->title
         $classes[] = "special-class";
 }
 return $classes;
}
```

Which checks if the item is a 'Page' and adds a class, but how can I add an item class to the children lis only if it is called 'Primary Nav' - guessing from:-

```
 wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Primary Nav' ));
```

Thanks

Glennyboy

Answer (score 0):

You can add them manually by going into the menu section, clicking screen options on the top, then clicking the CSS Classes box. This will make it so you can manually add a class for each item in the menu when you expand them.